# Possible to treat html that is directly outputted as a php string

Tags: php, html

I would simply like to know if something similar to this is possible in php somehow:

```
<?php
$myhtmlstring = "
?>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>test</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<?php
";
?>
```

The reason for this is I would like to be able to write the html in this nice looking format but have php trim the white space after the fact.

Comment: Have you **tried it**?  Does it do what you want it to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the alternative heredoc syntax:

```
$myhtmlstring = <<<EOT
<table>...</table>
EOT;
```

Or you can use [output buffering](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php):

```
<?php
ob_start();
?>

<table>...</table>

<?php
$myhtmlstring = ob_get_clean();
?>
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use [heredoc](http://php.net/heredoc).

Answer (score 3):

Yes

```
<?php
$myhtmlstring = '
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>test</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<?php
';
// Do what you want with the HTML in a PHP variable

// Echo the HTML from the PHP variable to make the webpage
echo $myhtmlstring;

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

I usually use the buffer functions, like so:

```
    <?php

    $whatever = "Hey man";

    // This starts the buffer, so output will no longer be written.
    ob_start();

    ?>
    <html>
      <head>
        <title><?php echo $whatever ?></title>
      </head>
      <body>
        <h1><?php echo $whatever ?></h1>
        <p>I like this in part because you can use variables.</p>
      </body>
    </html>
    <?php

    // Here's the magic part!
    $myhtmlstring = ob_get_clean();

    ?>
```

For more information about the buffer functions, look up `ob_start()` on
[php.net](http://php.net/).

Answer (score 0):

do you mean so?

```
<?php
 $string = '<table border="1">
  <tr>
   <td> test </td>
  </tr>
 </table>';
 echo $string;
 ?>
```